# How to read dat & idx file with C#?

Tags: c#, database, indexing, encode, binaryfiles

I have a dictionary data XML file (dict.xml) encoded into **dict.dat** & **dict.idx**.

I want to read 2 files with C#. Of coure, we cannot read normal text file with **StreamReader** because the contents look like this:

> €iêá!3n?ùq-ú4u)>ÿû43_fËðŸñÕrj©8EX7?s‹¹YÝO.Ðïá«íõúZþªæQª­¢ãèøè9ößôt'õìŽ6

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is encrypted with a key string.

You need to specify a key to decrypt dat file.

Besides, it also has indexing so you can read data faster with idx file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Encoding UTF8 to read one byte at a time or Unicode for two bytes at a time :             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Unicode);

Comment: Thanks jdweng. But the problem is not encoding. I think the data is encrypted.

Comment: Still if the data is encrypted you must use utf8.   StreamReader defaults to ASCII encoding which will filter ascii characters >= 128.  Your question was "HOW TO READ Text".  I answered that part of the question.  I cannot tell if the data is binary or encrypted.  It could be either.